# Dart programatically instantiating Polymer-elements from within .dart script

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm working on setting up a server-client test app in dart.

Right now the server/client connection is working fine.  One of the things I want to do though is add and remove custom elements from the page at various times.  Right now I have the code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:html';
import 'Signin/sign_in.dart';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';


class Client {
  static const Duration RECONNECT_DELAY = const Duration(milliseconds: 500);

  WebSocket webSocket;
  DivElement viewRoot;
  Client() {
     // Signin is a custom element defined...
    Signin sign = new Signin();
    viewRoot = $['hold-everything'];
    viewRoot.children.add(sign);


    connect();
  }
....
}
```

**sign_in.dart**

```dart
class Signin extends PolymerElement {

  Signin.created() : super.created();

  InputElement username;
  DivElement usernameParent;
  DivElement passwordParent;
  LabelElement usrWarn;
  LabelElement passWarn;
  LabelElement submissionWarn;
...
}
```

When I load the page I get the following error:

```
    [16:08:24.480] : NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'Symbol("constructor Signin")'
    Receiver: ""
    Arguments: [] @ http://localhost:8080/client.dart.js:1042
```

And in client.dart I have the following warning over

```
Signin sign = new Signin();
The class 'Signin' does not have a default constructor
```

Comment: I've figured this otu:  I needed ot add : 
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/index.html

to pubspec.yaml